# Requestanimationframe time parameter

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

I am using a simple requestanimationframe on a function that returns a console.log message. The problem is that first iteration start late at at around 200+ms. Is it my low pc? If I run it with inspect element opened it fires at 400.

```
function test(time) {
     console.log(time)
 requestAnimationFrame(time)
     }
```

Comment: [requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame#syntax) takes a callback parameter. What are you passing in for the `time` argument?

Comment: your code doesn't run, since there is no function called `time` - but, yes, the first callback will be many ms > 0 - because that's how time works - i.e. time doesn't start on the first callback to RAF ... it starts when the page loads